# How does the bowling computer know I'm right handed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, everyday-life

I went bowling the other day and after I rolled my first ball I was suprised it was written on the screen that I was "right-handed". How was that figured out?

*My first guess is that there is something different about the trajectory/spin of a ball rolled by a right and left-handed individual. But it seems difficult to ascertain which hand a bowler uses only from this because different bowlers bowl differently and some use a lot of spin while others don't.*

*My second guess is that the machine might use the fact that a right-handed person steps forward with their left leg when they bowl while a left-handed person steps forward with their right leg. However, this also seems difficult as I do not know what kind of sensor can be used to collect this information and also people might stand at different points in the aisle (left, center or right) when they bowl.*

Comment: There are several plausible guesses. Force sensors in the floor could both track your footfalls and measure the weight leant on each foot as the ball is launched: I'm sure which foot feels what weight would be consistently dependent on the sportsman's/woman's handedness. Or, more probably, it would simply photograph you as you launch the ball and detect which side the ball is on. The ball is probably very easy to spot with an image processing algorithm, being quite speculalarly reflective. To detect it relative to you and your face, that's really easy: think of how Facebook kens faces now.